# Target dependencies from variable in Makefile

Tags: makefile

(GNU Makefile)

I want a target that builds any library with the naming convention `lib*.so`, and depends upon a list of object files specified in a variable.

E.g. to build `libabc.so` would depend upon the `.o` files in the variable `abc_OBJS`.

I have tried `lib%.so: $($(%)_OBJS)`, but that's not right.

What is the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you cannot do this. GNU Make [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) explicitly states:

> Note that expansion using ‘%’ in pattern rules occurs **after** any
>   variable or function expansions, which take place when the makefile is
>   read.

`.SECONDEXPANSION` makes it work! (Note it's not SECONDARY, but SECOND)

The following `Makefile`:

```
abc_OBJS=a.o b.o c.o
def_OBJS=d.o e.o f.o

%.o:
    touch $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:

lib%.so: $$(%_OBJS)
    @echo $@ $^
```

Results in what you want!

```
$ make libabc.so libdef.so
touch a.o
touch b.o
touch c.o
libabc.so a.o b.o c.o
touch d.o
touch e.o
touch f.o
libdef.so d.o e.o f.o
rm a.o b.o c.o e.o d.o f.o
```

Note that if there's no rule to create the dependencies (`%.o:` rule) then the pattern rule does not match.

Comment: I've now come across `.SECONDARYEXPANSION`, and it works on the target dependencies line, but can't get it to work inside the target e.g. have secondary expansion variables inside the compiler steps etc.